# Error when I separate my CustomTkinter GUI from my main script

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, customtkinter

I'm trying to separate my GUI from my main code.  I have 2 files, `main.py` and `interface.py`.
When I run my `get_action` function (which is inside my main.py)I have the following error: `NameError: name 'app' is not defined` which is normal because my "app" is not global, but if I put it outside my program it does not run. How would I correct this?
Here's my code:

`main.py`:

```py
from interface import *

def get_action_mco():
    print(app.optionmenu_type_chaine.get())
```

`interface.py`:

```py
import customtkinter
from main import get_action

class App(customtkinter.CTk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.geometry("300x150")#taille de la fenetre graphique
        self.optionmenu_type_chaine = customtkinter.CTkOptionMenu(master=self, values=["", "Daily",      "Weekly", "Monthly"], width=200, height=30)
        self.optionmenu_type_chaine.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)
        self.button_recup_action = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=self,text="Cliquer ici",command=get_action, width= 200)
        self.button_recup_action_mco.grid(row=6, column=1, pady=5, padx=5)`
```

I have tried to :

- Create another function inside my `App` class named `load` and then then call `app.load` in my `main.py` file (still the same error).
- Put my `app = App()/app.mainloop()` outside of `if name=main`, but the program does not run.
- When I try to print `app.optionmenu_type_chaine.get()` outside the function (in my `main.py` file) it prints correctly when I close my program.

Comment: I can not add "if __name__=="__main__":
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()" in the begin of my main.py on stackoverflow, no idea why

Comment: For your case I think It is better to put `get_action_mco()` a class function of `App`.